# Playwright - check a Locator has only 1 element

Tags: arrays, e2e-testing, playwright

I'm using Playwright to locate all the `option` roles like so:

```
const autocompleteItem = page.getByRole('option');
```

And now i just want to check it return 1 element:

```
expect(autocompleteItem).toHaveLength(1);
```

But i get an error as the locator return an object and not an array...

Matcher error: received value must have a length property whose value must be a number

> Received has type:  object Received has value: {"_frame": {"_guid":
> "frame@da0ab90a509c7446b8566c8b7da167b5", "_type": "Frame"},
> "_selector": "internal:role=option"}
> at tests/e2e/playwright/index.test.ts:17:30

I need an explicit check this locator return 1 element...
Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the web first assertion [`toHaveCount()`](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-locatorassertions#locator-assertions-to-have-count) on the locator:

```
const autocompleteItem = page.getByRole('option');
await expect(autoCompleteItem).toHaveCount(1);
```

Comment: works like magic!

Answer (score 4):

`autocompletion` is a Locator object which has a [.count()](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-locator#locator-count) method.

You would await it and test the result

```js
const autocompleteItem = page.getByRole('option');
const count = await autocompleteItem.count()
expect(count).to.eq(1)
```

Comment: this is giving me:
Expected: 1
Received: {}